# location of file in perl

Tags: perl

As suggested by Chris, a user on this site. In the 1st perl script: The values are stored in the dictionary.The first script is fine.The first script runs for only one time and stores the values. It is working.

In the 2nd script:

my $processed = retrieve('processed_dirs.dat'); # $processed is a hashref

Here it is reading the "processed_durs.dat" which is in the first script. So, I am just wondering how the second script knows the location of Processed_dirs.dat here?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable;

# This script to be run 1 time only. Sets up 'processed' directories hash.
# After this script is run, ready to run the daily script.

my $dir = '.'; # or what ever directory the date-directories are stored in

opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Opening failed for directory $dir $!";
my @dir = grep {-d && /^\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$/ && $_ le '11-04-21'} readdir $dh;
closedir $dh or die "Unable to close $dir $!";

my %processed = map {$_ => 1} @dir;

store \%processed, 'processed_dirs.dat';
```

2nd Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;
use Storable;

my $dir = shift or die "Provide path on command line. $!";

my $processed = retrieve('processed_dirs.dat'); # $processed is a hashref

opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Opening failed for directory $dir $!";
my @dir = grep {-d && /^\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$/ && !$processed->{$_} } readdir $dh;
closedir $dh or die "Unable to close $dir $!";
@dir or die "Found no unprocessed date directories";

my $fdir = '/some/example/path';

for my $date (@dir) {
    my $dday = "$dir/$date";
    my @gzfiles = glob("$dday/*tar.gz");

    foreach my $zf (@gzfiles) {  
        next if $zf =~ /BMP/ || $zf =~ /LG/ || $zf =~ /MAP/ || $zf =~ /STR/; 
        print "$zf\n";
        copy($zf, $fdir) or die "Unable to copy $zf to $fdir. $!";
    }
    $processed->{ $date } = 1;
}
store $processed, 'processed_dirs.dat';
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, butI never hardcode filenames or directory names as a matter of principle, so if this were my script the answer would be clear: the information is on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, the answer is: Both scripts use a file called "`processed_dirs.dat`", in whatever directory they are run from. So as long as both scripts are run from the same directory, they will both use the same file.

Comment: The second actually requires a command line argument that identifies the directory where the first stored its data file.

Comment: @Jonathan: Not really. Although the second script requires a command line argument, it doesn't use it in constructing the path to open the data file (which is hardcoded as `processed_dirs.dat`)

Comment: I just run the first script by myself and the script script supposed to run by itself (automation ) as when I receive a folder in processed_dirs.dat, it checks this folder and run accordingly

Comment: So, I should make a folder in the same directory where both my script runs and name it as processed_dirs.dat??

Comment: Why would you think that you should create a directory? Your question was "how does the second script know the location of `processed_dirs.dat`"

Comment: I dont have any file with this name in my directory as of now.

Comment: Then something must be wrong with the first script, since that's what produces the file (or at least it's *supposed* to)

Comment: Yeah - I agree on second reading.  I didn't read the code carefully enough first time - just as well I didn't answer.